# Trying to access facebook friends on server side with given access token. OAuthException code => 2500 Error

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I am trying to retrieve the friends list of a user at server side using access token (Which the client code sends to me). I am using file_get_contents to retrieve the friends list and a RecursiveIteratorIterator to display it back on screen. Could someone guide me on how to solve the error?

```
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
    'ignore_errors'=>true,
    'method'=>'POST'

)
));

$response = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/me/friendsaccess_token=".$token, false, $context));


    $jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveArrayIterator($response, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST));

    foreach ($jsonIterator as $key => $val) {
        if(is_array($val)) {
            echo "$key:\n";
        } else {
            echo "$key => $val\n";
    }
```

error:

```
message => Unknown path components:/friendsaccess_token=<Access_Token>
type => OAuthException
code => 2500
```

Comment: through with the problem? Please mark an answer and close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the `access_token` in the query string. So put a question mark (`?`) in the URL request after `friends`.

```
$response = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=".$token, false, $context));
```

Comment: This was evident from the error message, `Unknown path components:/friendsaccess_token=<Access_Token>` that you were getting

Comment: Thanks for the response. I now am getting "message => (#100) type => OAuthException code => 100". Could you help me out with it?

Comment: try changing the method from POST to `GET`